# Python - fill NA by value from previous rows based on identifier column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I would like to fill missing value in 2 columns. There are Date and Cat2 should be filled with the value of another row based on the last date for predefined Cat1 (predefined in previous filled rows), for example:

Data Example:

```
Day  Date      Cat1      Cat2
1    31/12/17  cat       mouse
2    01/09/18  cat       mouse
3    27/05/18  dog       elephant
4       NaN    cat       NaN
5       NaN    cat       NaN
```

So,  `NaN` of `Date` column should be filled based on the last existed date for `cat` values from `Cat1` column - `01/09/18`. The `NaN` in `Cat2` column should be filled by `mouse` as defined values in row which has already selected for `Date` - `01/09/18`.

I read that looping through each row would be very bad practice and that it would be better to do everything in one way.

I'd appreciate for any idea.Thanks)

I tried to do it by `fillna` method, but it fill by last values without condition for Cat1.

```
data.fillna(method='ffill', inplace = True)
```

Actual result is:

```
Day  Date      Cat1      Cat2
1    31/12/17  cat       mouse
2    01/09/18  cat       mouse
3    27/05/18  dog       elephant
4    27/05/18  cat       elephant
5    27/05/18  cat       elephant
```

Expected result should be:

```
Day  Date      Cat1      Cat2
1    31/12/17  cat       mouse
2    01/09/18  cat       mouse
3    27/05/18  dog       elephant
4    01/09/18  cat       mouse
5    01/09/18  cat       mouse
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same order like original `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.groupby('Cat1').ffill().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df)
   Day      Date Cat1      Cat2
0    1  31/12/17  cat     mouse
1    2  01/09/18  cat     mouse
2    3  27/05/18  dog  elephant
3    4  01/09/18  cat     mouse
4    5  01/09/18  cat     mouse
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. ```Date``` column is filled correctly by last date for ```Cat1```, but  ```Cat2``` column was filled without condition for ```Cat1``` (```elephant``` insead of ```mouse```).

Comment: @@Jezrael, you are right. I understand where is my issue. Before executing suggested ```df.groupby('Cat1').ffill().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)```, I run ```sort_values``` as like: ```data.sort_values(by=['Date'], inplace=True, ascending=True)```. So, I suppose that's why was issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Cindy - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Also, alternative way is:

```
data = data.groupby(['Cat1'], as_index = False).apply(lambda group: group.ffill())
```

Thanks, @Jezrael for idea of solution:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict:

```
dict = df[['cat','cat2']].drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=False).to_dict()
df['cat2'] = df['cat1'].replace(dict)
```

for timeseries-column you can using timedelta (linear extrapolation). good luck!